# Вывод таблицы в 2(3) колонки

Tags: php

Всем привет)
через этот код выводится информация о товарах.
есть разделы о товарах в которых 30 чекбоксов и выводятся они одним вертикальным списком (страшно не красиво), хотелось бы чтобы выводилось в 3 колонках ..
подскажите как ?

```
<?php if ( !defined('ABS_PATH') ) {
    exit('ABS_PATH is not loaded. Direct access is not allowed.');
}
?>
    <table class="sss">
        <tbody>
<?php
$hide_empty = osc_get_preference('hide_empty', CA_PLUGIN_NAME);
foreach ($fields as $field):
   $value = Attributes::newInstance()->getValue($item_id, $field['pk_i_id']);
   if (!empty($hide_empty) && 'hide' == $hide_empty) {
      if ('checkbox' != $field['s_type'] && '' == trim($value)) {
         continue;
      }
   } 
   if ($field['s_type'] == 'checkbox'){
    if($value != 'checked')
        continue;
    else
        $value = '';
}
?>
    <tr class="ddd">
        <td class='detail_label'><?=$field['s_label']?></td>
        <td class='detail_label1'><?=$value?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php //END
```

Comment: вероятно, надо разделить список на 2(3) части и в строке (`<tr>...</tr>`) выводить сразу по 2(3) элемента списка.

Comment: да именно здесь, и надо.. но как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще всего заюзать CSS-свойство [`columns`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/). Примеры и объяснения по ссылке выше. [На хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/company/microsoft/blog/143158/).

```css
#example{
    -webkit-columns: 200px 3;
    -moz-columns: 200px 3;
    columns: 200px 3;
}
```

```html
<div id='example'>
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
    <input type='checkbox' /><br />
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7s28jezn/).

**UPD:**

В таблице 30 боксов проще разместить изменив генерацию, увеличив количество ячеек в строке.

Можно изобретать велосипеды типа проверок на длину/количество/метафизические_свойства, перестраивать таблицу в соответствии с правилами, но это кошер не одобрит, только индусам это дозволено. Как-то так:

```
<table class="sss">
    <tr class="ddd">
        <td class="detail_label">рядом метро</td>
        <td class="detail_label1"></td>
        <td class="detail_label">благоустроенный двор</td>
        <td class="detail_label1"></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: спасибо за подсказки, НО у меня выводится в таблице это все, мне бы желательно для таблицы (как я понимаю надо в самом коде делить), а  не css

Comment: Без исходных данных сложно воссоздать страницу. Я понятия не имею что будет после генерации, приведите, пожалуйста, кусок уже созданной таблицы.

Comment: @Иван, Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Можно начать отталкиваться от следующего примера

```
<?php
  $filename = range(1, 12);
  // Вычисляем количество элементов в массиве
  $total = count($filename);
  // Количество столбцов в таблице
  $numcols = 3;

  // Вычисляем количество строк
  $number = (int)($total / $numcols);
  if((float)($total / $numcols) - $number != 0) $number++;

  // Формируем промежуточный двумерный массив
  $arr = [];
  for($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < $numcols; $j++) {
      $arr[$i][$j] = $filename[$j*$number + $i];
    }
  } 

  // Выводим таблицу
  echo "<table>";
  for($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for($j = 0; $j < $numcols; $j++) {
      echo "<td>".$arr[$i][$j]."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
  } 
  echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="sss"> 
<tbody>
<tr class="ddd">
<td class="detail_label">рядом метро</td>
<td class="detail_label1"></td>
 </tr>
<tr class="ddd">
<td class="detail_label">благоустроенный двор</td>
<td class="detail_label1"></td>
</tr>
```

то что выводится по результату

Comment: дополните, пожалуйста, этой информацией свой вопрос (ссылка под словом «править»), а этот «ответ», не являющийся ответом, пожалуйста, удалите (ссылка под словом «удалить»).